# JQUERY using equivalent and for each together

Tags: jquery

I have this simple HTML page:

```
<html>

   <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul li:eq(1)').each(function(){
           alert($(this).text());
        });
   });
   </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>Test</li>
         <li>Pop</li>
         <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
         <li>Test</li>
         <li>Pop</li>
         <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
         <li>Test</li>
         <li>Pop</li>
         <li>Test</li>
      </ul> 
   </body>

</html>
```

I want to loop through all the Ul's and alert the text value of the second li in each list.
So the code above should alert the word `pop` 3 times. However, it alerts only 1 time.

How to use `eq` correctly in the above case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). The [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector will return the element at the passed index, in this case 1 against all the elements passed to it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li:nth-child(2)').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to use `:eq()`, you need to pass the filter as a second level filter like

```js
$('ul').find('li:eq(1)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

In this case first it will find all the 3 `ul` elements, then will iterate through each one and will call `.find('li:eq(1)')` in each one independent of each other.